# Laravel 8.16 "Class name must be a valid object or a string"

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-8, spatie

Estoy implementando el paquete `spatie/laravel-permission` para implementar roles  y permisos en mi aplicación de Vue.Js pero cuando intento recuperar los roles que no tiene un usuario asignado me muestra un error, en la siguiente consulta:

```
 public function edit(User $user){
     ...
     $availableRoles = Role::whereDoesntHave('users', function (Builder $query) use ($user){
        $query->where('id', $user->id);
     })->get();
 }
 ...
```

Ya he intentando de todo pero me sigue saliendo este error:

[image: error]

mi controlador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el archivo de paquete que parece fallar :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Origen del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje de error te debería estar indicando donde se original el error, lo puedes agregar a tu pregunta?

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta, gracias de antemano